# Time conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a spread sheet where a cell will turn Green then Yellow Than Red based on time pasted from time recorded. I was using:

```
=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)-C2)<2  as Green

=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)-D1)<4  as Yellow

=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)-D1)>=4  as Red
```

But every thing is going red I am using conditional formatting and cells are formatted as `HH:MM AM/PM`

Comment: Why do you have MOD()? Hour returns a number, don't know what C2 or D1 so it's hard to say what is wrong

Comment: D1 is the cell with the time I changed the other 2 in the sheet for got to change it here but all are looking at D1 as the "start time" and needs to change color depending on the amount of time passed like Red as " 4 hrs have passed"

Comment: Does D1 contain the time? Or does it contain the date/time formatted to show just the time portion?  And, if it contains a date/time, what colour do you want to use if it is 27 hours old?  (Or does D1 contain a text string that looks like a time?)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can replicate your problem is if D1 contains a date/time, and not just a time.

Say you have a date/time in that cell of 17 Nov 2016 6:50 AM (displayed in `HH:MM AM/PM` format as "06:50 AM") and say it is now 17 Nov 2016 7:59 AM.

Your calculation will be attempting to calculate the HOUR of 0.28472222 (the numeric value for 6:50 AM on 0 Jan 1900) less 42691.33264 (the numeric value for 7:59 AM on 17 Nov 2016).  An `HOUR(-42691.04792)` issues a `#NUM!` error (as negative values are invalid for date/time calculations) and will give you problems in your conditional formatting.

If you **do** have a date/time in cell D1 (even though it is formatted to just **display** the time portion), then you can either use the following formulae if you want an elapsed time of 27 hours to display as red:

```
=(NOW()-D1)*24<2    as Green
=(NOW()-D1)*24<4    as Yellow
=(NOW()-D1)*24>=4   as Red
```

or use the following formulae if you want an elapsed time of 27 hours to be treated the same as 3 hours and formatted as yellow:

```
=HOUR(NOW()-D1)<2    as Green
=HOUR(NOW()-D1)<4    as Yellow
=HOUR(NOW()-D1)>=4   as Red
```

Comment: Thank you that got it. Department wanted the sheet to reflect even if 24 hours past.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into pieces to make sure each portion of your function is acting as expected. I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but I've broken down each piece of your example. Using this info you should be able to see where the output becomes incorrect and fix the logic. Let me know if it helps but you aren't quite there.

**What you have:**

fx: `=NOW()`

Output: `11/16/2016 15:16`

fx: `=MOD(NOW(),1)`

Output: `1/0/1900 15:16`

fx: `=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1))`

Output: `15`

fx: `=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)-D1)`

Output: `15 - HOUR(D1)` (as a number)

Is `15 - HOUR(D1)` the number you expect to be using in your comparison? If not, you've got an error in your logic. If it is, you probably have an error in your conditional formatting.

HTH, let us know what you come up with.

Jackson

Edits:

- Corrected `=MOD(NOW(),1)` in second formula line

Comment: The OP is using `MOD(NOW(),1)`, not `MOD(NOW())`.  `MOD(NOW(),1)` will ignore the date part of the date/time, leaving just the time part.

Comment: That's a typo above, I've corrected it to say `=MOD(NOW(),1)`. That being said, I'm not familiar with using the MOD function with dates. Why not just use `=HOUR(NOW()-D1)` instead of `=HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)-D1)`? When will `HOUR(MOD(NOW(),1)` not equal `HOUR(NOW())`?

Comment: I noticed your edit at almost the same time as I left my comment - but I left the comment to point out that `MOD(NOW(),1)` is just stripping off the date portion of NOW(), mainly because of your comment that it would return a nonsensical value.   Personally, I wouldn't use `MOD(NOW(),1)`, but some people prefer to explicitly convert it to just the time because that is how they think.  I also don't like using `HOUR` on a timespan (I just use timespan*24) but it would be useful if you want to exclude the elapsed days portion of the timespan (i.e. it saves doing a MOD 24).

Comment: Interestingly it strips the date to what it reads as a "zero value" for date. If you multiply the result of a `MOD(NOW(),1)` by a large integer it still associates the date portion to the time, counting days as its "hundreds" (where minutes and hours are 1s and 10s). I agree with your answer of simply omitting the `MOD(NOW(),1)` and shooting straight for the `HOUR` function. Now if he can just accept it for you... :)